# How to Create a function that returns the total number of boomerangs in an array

Tags: ruby, algorithm

A boomerang is a V-shaped sequence that is either upright or upside down. Specifically, a boomerang can be defined as: sub-array of length 3, with the first and last digits being the same and the middle digit being different.
Some boomerang examples:

```
[3, 7, 3], [1, -1, 1], [5, 6, 5]
```

Create a function that returns the total number of boomerangs in an array.
To illustrate:

```
[3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, -2, 2]
# 3 boomerangs in this sequence:  [3, 7, 3], [1, 5, 1], [2, -2, 2]
```

Be aware that boomerangs can overlap, like so:

```
[1, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7, 1]
# 5 boomerangs (from left to right): [1, 7, 1], [7, 1, 7], [1, 7, 1], [7, 1, 7], and [1, 7, 1]
```

Examples:

```
count_boomerangs([9, 5, 9, 5, 1, 1, 1]) ➞ 2
count_boomerangs([5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 3, 9]) ➞ 1
count_boomerangs([4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9]) ➞ 0
```

Note:
[5, 5, 5] (triple identical digits) is NOT considered a boomerang because the middle digit is identical to the first and last.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that StackOverflow is *not* a coding service. Instead of copy-pasting what I assume is an assignment, please show what you've tried and ask specific questions about the problem you encounter. You can find additional help on the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some verbose way to do this:

```
class Array
  def same_values?
    self.uniq.length == 1
  end
end

def find_boomerangs(arr)
  split_amount = 3 # count of a possible boomerang
  scan_amount = split_amount - 1 # scanning by index for array
  new_arr = []
  arr.each_with_index { |_, indx| # we only care for the indx
    end_of_indx = indx + scan_amount
    arry = arr[indx .. end_of_indx] # collect new possible boomerang from array
    next unless arry.count == split_amount # only check if possible boomerang is length of three

    new_arr << arry if arry.values_at(0, -1).same_values? && !arry.values_at(0, 1).same_values? # checks that the values at the start and end are the same and that the middle value is not the same as the first
  }
  new_arr # holds the boomerangs | call .count if you want the count
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Very simple approach (sorry, in Python):

```
def boomerangs(l):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(l) - 2):
        if l[i] == l[i+2] and l[i] != l[i+1]:
            count += 1
    return count

print(boomerangs([3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, -2, 2]))
print(boomerangs([1, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7, 1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def count_boomerangs(arr)
  arr.each_cons(3).count { |a,b,c| a == c && a !=b }
end
```

```
count_boomerangs [3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, -2, 2] #=> 3
count_boomerangs [1, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7, 1]              #=> 5
count_boomerangs [9, 5, 9, 5, 1, 1, 1]              #=> 2
count_boomerangs [5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 3, 9]              #=> 1
count_boomerangs [4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9]              #=> 0
```

See [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Answer (score 0):

```py
get_bommerangs = lambda arr: sum(
    arr[i - 1] == arr[i + 1] and arr[i - 1] != arr[i] for i in range(1, len(arr) - 1)
)

bommerangs = get_bommerangs([2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?